# React - want to toggle active class on children elements of hamburger dropdown component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, hamburger-menu

I'm making a custom 3-line hamburger dropdown component. To get my question out of the way: I would like to toggle an active class on children components - namely, 3 spans making up the 3 lines, within a wrapping span:

```
<span id="closebtn">
  <span class="line1" />
  <span class="line2" />
  <span class="line3" />
</span>
```

and I'm not quite sure how.

I had it working before but with a mix of React and jQuery (I know, I know). With jQuery the code looked like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let close = document.getElementById("closebtn");

  close.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let menuIcon = close.children;
    for (let i = 0; i < menuIcon.length; i++) {
      menuIcon[i].classList.toggle("active");
    }
  });
```

I'm converting my project to pure React and trying to get the same effect to work - namely, when you click the dropdown it toggles an active class on all three children components and the 3 lines transform into an X. Here's the code:

```
class NavButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { isOpen: false };

    this.toggleButton = this.toggleButton.bind(this);
  }

  toggleButton() {
    // ...do something...

    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  }

  render() {
    let children = this.props.children;

    return (
      <span id="closebtn" onClick={this.toggleButton}>
        {children}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

And the button is now set up like so:

```
  <NavButton>
    <span className="line1" />
    <span className="line2" />
    <span className="line3" />
  </NavButton>
```

I thought I might have to make an extra component, something like NavButtonLine to stand in for the three inner spans, and play around with the state of those components but I'm not too sure how to go about it.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why not to render spans as a part of render method of NavButton?

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this is

```
import cx from 'classnames';

class NavButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { isOpen: false };

    this.toggleButton = this.toggleButton.bind(this);
  }

  toggleButton() {
    // ...do something...

    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  }

  render() {
    let children = this.props.children;
    const activeClass = classnames({
      active: this.state.isOpen,
    });

    return (
      <span id="closebtn" onClick={this.toggleButton}>
        <span className="line1" className={activeClass} />
        <span className="line2" className={activeClass} />
        <span className="line3" className={activeClass} />
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

To make it more scalable you can loop over the children and the `active` to them. Refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Comment: Ah interesting. What is cx in this case? Also is there a way to avoid the "duplicate key 'className' "? I did an npm install of classnames but the code doesn't compile, saying 'classnames is not defined'.

Comment: Oh I got around the duplicate key problem by concatenating: 
<span className={"line1" + activeClass}/>